# Count likes on url shared with Share dialog

Tags: facebook, share

I''d like to know if there's a way to get likes and shares on a url shared with the Share Dialog;I'm trying to use the standard ?id=http://example.com/page/xxx-xxx but it's only counting shares if I share the link in my status update

It's not about time, I'm trying also with posts (and by post I mean created with the share dialog) made 2 days ago, and the one I shared on my status is updated istantly

Also even with a read_stream permission I don't see the post shared with the dialog (using /me/posts/), just the one shared on my status; that's pretty weird... (I'm testing with the GraphApi Explorer Tool)

Can someone provide help, please?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with share dialog not increasing the share count. It was also ignoring any custom message added by the user. Solved it by using sharer.php, I read somewhere that is not deprecated anymore but I couldn't find any official info about that, so it's not an optimal solution but it'll work until i can figure out what's wrong with share dialog.

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fsample-post%2F
```

You can't send custom parameters to sharer.php anymore, the only one accepted is 'u'. Use open graph tags on the target page to specify title, description, images, etc.

Using the following to get shares

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fsample-post%2F
```

will only return a "shares" attribute which is the sum of likes and shares (and maybe comments, not sure).

```
{ "id": "http://www.example.com/sample-post/", "shares": 3 }
```

If you want to get a more detailed count you can query the table link_stat using FQL and the open graph API.

Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count 
FROM link_stat 
WHERE url="http://www.example.com/sample-post/"
```

and your request should look something like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fsample-post%2F%0A%22
```

This will return all the queried info in JSON:

```
{
   "data": [
  {
     "url": "http://www.example.com/sample-post/",
     "normalized_url": "http://www.example.com/sample-post/",
     "share_count": 3,
     "like_count": 0,
     "comment_count": 0,
     "total_count": 3,
     "commentsbox_count": 0,
     "comments_fbid": 123456789012345,
     "click_count": 0
      }
]}
```

Another way to get this information is to use the link.getStats method:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fsample-post%2F&format=json
```

This method is deprecated but you can still use it for testing purposes, it will also return JSON.

```
[{
"url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/sample-post\/",
"normalized_url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/sample-post\/",
"share_count":3,
"like_count":0,
"comment_count":0,
"total_count":3,
"click_count":0,
"comments_fbid":123456789012345,
"commentsbox_count":0}]
```

Is anyone else having problems with the share dialog?